# How to limit the size of each group in SQL?

Tags: sql

E.g. I have a table that looks like this:

```
(ID, TEXT, CLASS)
(0L, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
(1L, "b d", 0.0),
(2L, "spark f g h", 1.0),
(3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0),
(3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 1.0),
(4L, "b spark who", 1.0),
(5L, "g d a y", 0.0),
(6L, "spark fly", 1.0),
(7L, "was mapreduce", 0.0),
(8L, "e spark program", 1.0),
(9L, "a e c l", 0.0),
(10L, "spark compile", 1.0),
(11L, "hadoop software", 0.0)
```

I want to select a table that limit the size of each class to 2, while only keep the rows that has smallest IDs, is there an SQL command that can do this?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's important to show us what you have tried in order to solve this yourslef. Also, a visual example of your expected output can help us more to understand what it is that you need.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI standard method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by class order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Most (but not all) databases support this functionality.